# Find possible distances between C and E

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> A, B, C, D and E lies on a line, not necessarily in that order.
>   Distance between A and B is $2$, distance between B and C is $3$, distance
>   between C and D is $5$ and distance between D and E is $4$.  Find  the possible 
>   distances between C and E?

I find this type of problems difficult to solve. I don't understand clearly about the orders. In this particular case, I think if A, B, C, and D are placed in order and E is placed in both sides of D, then two possible distances are possible between C and E, which is $9$ and $1$. But what if possible distances between A and E are to be found? Can anyone clearly elaborate the process and concepts behind these line problems?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us denote by lower case letters $a,b,c,d,e$ the abscissas of points $A,B,C,D,E$ resp.

Two basic observations about this issue:

- it is "up to a translation" which allows to take $E$ as the origin, i.e., $e=0$.
- it is "up to a symmetry", which allows $D$ to be set at abscissa $d \geq 0$.

Consider the two last constraints, the other constraints being **useless**.

$$\begin{cases}|c-d|&=&5\\d&=&4\end{cases} \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ |c-4|=5.$$

Thus 2 cases:

- $c=-1$; thus $CE=1$.
- $c=9$; thus $CE=9$.

Edit: Here is a tree explaining how the other possible positions of points $A,B,C$ can be found (truly speaking,  it is not exactly a tree because two branches meet in a "leaf"...). Taking a branch in the upwards direction like $(A_3,B_1,C_1,D)$ provides a solution ($E$ being fixed).

[image]

Comment: Now if I solve |b-c| = 3 for c=-1 and c=9, then I find 4 values of b, which are 2 -4, 12 and 6. Are all these distance between B and E? If so, then we get 8 possible distances of A and E, right?

Comment: It's right, 4, (resp 8) possible positions for $B$ (resp. A). If I have time, I will show how a tree helps to visualize it.

Comment: See my Edit. In fact it is not 8 but 7 possible positions for $A$. Nevertheless there are 8 types of solution $(a,b,c,d,e)$.

Comment: Thank you... for saying thank you.

Answer (score -1):

given
equation1 $b-a = 2$

equation2 $c-b = 3$

equation3 $d-c = 5$

equation4 $e-d = 4$

need to find $e - c$ and $e - a$
solution:

add equation3 and equation4 and you get $e-c = 9$

add all of them and you get $e - a = 14$

Comment: The points needn't be in the order $A$, $B$, $C$, $D$, $E$.